# how to fetch feed from facebook page in flutter/dart?

Tags: android, facebook, http, flutter, dart

i want to display public page feed from facebook in my flutter app i have tried some plugins but no responce, Im new to flutter. is it possible to fetch data without permissions ?

Comment: you can use webview.

Comment: but it will load the whole site.

Comment: i tried web view, but i would like to have more control so im looking for some kind of api call

Comment: hi, I used the facebook page plugin code in my flutter website, used html element view widget to display the feeds. but there are lot many performance issues, you got any reference to complete this tasks ?

Answer (score -1):

I have seen tutorial for it

Step 1: Add the following dependency in your pubspec.yaml file. Do make sure that you use the latest version of the package.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_facebook_login: ^1.1.1
```

Step 2: On the URL below, complete steps 1 to 6.

https://digiworld.surf/docs/facebook-login/android?__cpo=aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXJzLmZhY2Vib29rLmNvbQ

Step 3: Add the app_name string in strings.xml with it’s value being the name of your Android app. If the strings.xml file doesn’t exist, go ahead and create a new one under: android > app > src > main > res > values

Step 4: Import the following package in your main.dart file:

Step 5: Create a new method that handles Facebook login:

Step 6: The onLoginStatusChanged(...) method is just used to update the UI using setState() when the user logs in successfully:

On iOS, the app crashes. This is because we haven’t configured Facebook login for iOS. Follow the steps given below for the same:

Step 1: On the URL below, complete steps 1 to 4.

https://digiworld.surf/docs/facebook-login/ios?__cpo=aHR0cHM6Ly9kZXZlbG9wZXJzLmZhY2Vib29rLmNvbQ

Step 2: Do….nothing! You’ve already setup your Flutter code. Nothing else needs to be done. Simply go ahead and run your app on an iOS device

Comment: Your answer is different from the question. Question is not about Facebook authentication.

Comment: Please read q's before answering, this is not what OP meant